# How to evaluate the code passed to the `parenscript:ps` macro?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, parenscript

How can I evaluate the code passed to the `ps` macro in Parenscript?

```lisp
(let ((x 1))
  (format nil "~a" (parenscript:ps x))) 
;; => "x;" but I would like "1;"
```

I know that `ps` is a macro and is the reason to not evaluate, but how to can I evaluate the code to passing to `ps` macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example using `ps:lisp`:

```lisp
(let ((x 1))
  (format nil "~a" (ps:ps (ps:lisp x))))
"1;"
```

It is introduced in the first section of the documentation: https://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/reference.html#section-ps-compiler

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
(defmacro lisp-to-js (lisp)
  (eval ``(parenscript:ps ,,lisp)))
(let ((x 1))
  (format nil "~a" (lisp-to-js x)))
;; => "1;"
```

Comment: Isn't it what `ps:lisp` is for?